# `pip help install` raise UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, pip

When I tried to use pip to install Cython, I found that an error occurred while compiling. And some basic pip command also gave the same result: `UnicodeDecodeError`.

The error messages are all like this:

```
─➤  pip help install
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 126, in main
    self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip/commands/help.py", line 19, in run
    command.parser.print_help()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/optparse.py", line 1664, in print_help 
    file.write(self.format_help().encode(encoding, "replace"))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe4 in position 2964: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I have successfully installed other packages by pip and I don't know why this occurs suddenly. Can anyone tell me how to fix this bug?

Thank you!

Some info:
pip 1.0.2 on Ubuntu 10.04

Comment: There is a newer version of pip available (1.1). Have you tried on this newer version?

Comment: Yap I've upgrade to 1.1 but the problem still exists

Comment: Have a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134071/cant-use-pip-anymore

Comment: This usually relates to older version pip, so just upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an exact solution, but try to check:

```bash
[user@host]$ locale
```

For me it looks like this:

```
[w495@w-495-ynb ~]$ locale
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=C
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY=C
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT=C
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I suppose that problem is in it.

You can try to set locale variables in command line by manualy yourself.
For example:

```
[user@host]$ LANG=en_US.utf8
[user@host]$ pip help install
```

I'm not sure that exactly `LANG` helps you. If not — try all from `locale` output. If it works, set it permanently if you want. Put this

```
export LANG=en_US.utf8
export <ANY OTHER VAR THAT HELPS>=en_US.utf8
```

in your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` and use

```
[user@host]$ source ~/.bashrc
```

to apply your changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access on server, try:

```
nano /usr/lib/python2.6/sitecustomize.py, and write on file:
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the terminal:

```
$ which python
```

and

```
$ which pip
```

Pip should be from the same Python install as the interpreter you're using. If they're not the same modify your .bashrc or .bash_profile to make sure they are.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

it will install pip respective python version.

Answer (score 0):

first of all update all packages/repositories using
sudo apt-get update
The newest Cython release can always be downloaded from http://cython.org. Unpack the tarball or zip file, enter the directory, and then run:
python setup.py install
or
pip install cython

Answer (score 0):

Remove `pip` using following command:

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pip
```

Then install a fresh copy of `pip`:

```
curl  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python
```

Answer (score 0):

When I was installing modules onto my computer to use, I was taught to just type in the following into the command prompt (for example, this would be installing numpy):

```
>install pip numpy
```

I don't know if you're typing this into an interpreter, but that may be a problem. Hope this helps!